# best way for set value base class property in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: inheritance, asp.net-mvc-5

i have a asp.net mvc project with UnitOfWork and 4 layerd : 
1.Data Layer
2. Domain Class
3. Service Layer
4. UI Layer ( Controller , View , ...)
i have a base class for shared propety like Id, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate :

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }

public class Customer : BaseClass
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

i want when a record is inserted, set value for CreatedBy and CreatedDate and when a record updated then set value for ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate.
i do not know how to do this?
i do not know which layer to do it?
thank's.

Answer (score 0):

i know two solution.But I don't know which one is better.
**solution 1** :
in Data Layer and in Repository Class i set values for them :

```
public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    IDbSet<T> _entities;
    public EFRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _entities = _unitOfWork.Set<T>();
    }
    public int Add(T entity)
    {
        (entity as BaseClass).CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        (entity as BaseClass).RowState = DomainClasses.Enums.State.Confirmed;
        _entities.Add(entity);
        return _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    public int Delete(T entity)
    {
        (entity as BaseClass).RowState = DomainClasses.Enums.State.Canceled;
        _unitOfWork.MarkAsChanged<T>(entity);
        return _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

**Solution 2 :**
i set values in UI Layer ( in Controller ) and Pass Entity to Repository class but i don't know how to implement it.
thank's.